# Use CSR in Next.js as fallback when SSR path is not available

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So I have this blog, with dynamic url for posts (blog/[postId]). Posts are being added through keystone.js cms. It worked fine via CSR, but i came to a necessity to add proper meta open graph tags for each post (for correct share snippets).

I added getStaticProps and getStaticPaths to my post page, and now my meta tags are working fine, but now i get 404 when trying to access any post, that was added after build. Meaning, now i have to rebuild after each new post. My question is - is it possible to set Next to render component as CSR, if it fails to find path for it with getStaticPaths? I've tried to use try catch, but that didn't work. Now i came up with this concept of using container, but it does not seem to be the right way to use fallback. Or is it? I am fairly new to Next, so i am a bit confused.

```html
const PostContainer = (props) => {
  
  const [postData, setPostData] = React.useState(null);

  const router = useRouter();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (router.query?.id) {
      getPost();
    }
  }, [router.query]);

  const getPost = async () => {
    const postData = await getPost(`${router.query.id}`);
  
    if (postData) {
      setPostData(postData);
    }
  };

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <Post data={postData}
                 metaProps={defaultMetaProps}
           />
  }

  return (
  <Post data={postData}
        metaProps={props}
  />
  );
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const list = await getPosts();

  if (list?.length) {
    const paths = list.map((post) => {
      return {
        params: {
          id: post.id,
        },
      };
    });
    
    return {
      paths,
      fallback: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    paths: [],
    fallback: true,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const { id } = params;
  const post = await getPost(id);

  const {title, description, previewImage} = post
  
  const props = {
    props: {
      title,
      description,
      url: `https://sitename./blog/${id}`,
      image: previewImage,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
  return props
};

export default PostContainer;
```

And one more thing - do i understand correctly that if fallback option is true, it takes only one visit to the page by ANY user, after which new path is generated on the server permanently and is accessible for anyone who comes next, therefore fallback always fires just once for this first visit of first user?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, fallback works that way. And doesn't that solve your problem? New pages should be generated in runtime after the first visit. Do you have any errors or something? You are not using `next export`, right?

Comment: You may wanna look at [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) which is built for this use-case (among others)

Comment: @PsyGik he already using it

Comment: @Danila nope, not using next export. As for problem - well this container thingy seem to work fine, my question was if i am using fallback right with this solution, since i have this feeling that i am reinventing things.

Comment: It is totally fine to use that approach. I just though you had `404` error with it, but your code looks fine, there should be no errors

Comment: Oh i see. Thanks for clarifying this for me.